# Using media query and show a div below another div which is written before

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

Hello all what i am trying to do is that i have a HTML page where i have 2 divs div1 and div2 both are float left and obviously div1 comes before div2 but what i want is that with the help of media query i want div1 to get below div2 as soon as page size gets below 400px

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .div1,
  .div2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left;width:50%;height:100%;" class='div1'>//1

</div>
<div style="float:left;width:50%;height:100%;" class='div2'>//2

</div>
```

The code is right but the div comes before div2 i want div2 to come before div1 .

can anyone please suggest me something .
this is just a test html i have more divs in page.

Comment: You can't do that just with CSS. Also you have mistakes in your code like missing collon between .div1 and .div2 in your style.

Comment: any ideas how to do it without changing my html and only on mobile devices means leser than 400 px

Comment: You can use jquery prepend function or insertBefore to do that depending on window width. More info here http://api.jquery.com/prepend/ and here http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/

Comment: Do you have the jQuery library in your project? You could do it with that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ordering in css with 100% width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267309/ordering-in-css-with-100-width)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with CSS3 flexbox layout.

1. Wrap a parent container over the two elements. Set flex display and direction to be column(for vertical placement)
2. Reorder your first div to be second element using `order: 2`

```css
@media (max-width: 800px) { /* Change this to 400px, 800px for demo purpose */
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* For vertical placement of items */
  }
  .div1 {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="float:left;width:50%;height:100%;" class='div1'>
    1
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;width:50%;height:100%;" class='div2'>
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to know that flex is a CSS3 feature and will not work in older versions of IE.

Comment: If the OP needs to support <IE10, then he/she would not use it. Otherwise, IE is something not to worry about.

Comment: That's true. I just wanted to inform him about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with plain CSS3 Flexbox model.
try out the following code:-
Apply the following style to parent element

```css
parent-element {
  display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
}
```

And in media queries target the child element you want to move, in your case it would be:-

```css
@media (max-width:400px) {
    div2 {
       order: 1;
    }
    div1 {
       order:2;
    }
}
```

This code would work fine.

Comment: You need to know that flex is a CSS3 feature and will not work in older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jquery:

```js
if ($(window).width() < 400) {
   $('.div2').insertBefore('.div1');
}
```